# Blender 2.77 Cycles: branched path tracing AA samples missing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, interface

I'm using Blender 2.77 to render using Cycles. 
I wish to render some SSS on a candle and read that *branched path tracing* can help a lot with the quality. The thing is, I can't increase my sample count more than 4. The samples do not do anything and I don't have the AA samples there. Where is that setting?

Comment: That setings is in the Properties editor > Render tab > *Sampling* rollout. Why can't you increase samples count > 4, what prevents ? So you see them but can't increase ? If you could post screenshots of what the problem is that would clarify the question quite a bit.

Comment: I just didn't have the AA samples rollout whatsoever and that's what controls the branched path tracing sample count. However, I upgraded my Blender to 2.78a and it's all fine so no further assistance needed. All your help appreciated.